# matemask Ropsten Test Network buy ETH from faucet

Tags: ethereum

```
{"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"Too Many Requests\",\"data\":{\"originalError\":{}},\"stack\":\"Error: Too Many Requests\\n    at /www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:51:23\\n    at Request._callback (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:53:11)\\n    at Request.self.callback (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)\\n    at Request.emit (events.js:310:20)\\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)\\n    at Request.emit (events.js:310:20)\\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)\\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)\\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)\\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)\"}}'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests for ether after the first request, within 24 hours, receive the "too many requests" message. You can check that your request is in the queue at https://faucet.dimensions.network/ .
I am not aware if there are other conditions that may result in the same error.